Impact of HDFS replication factor on namenode memory
Does increasing replication factor increases namenode memory usage in HDFS?
This link states replication factor do not have impact on namenode memory usage but another link states otherwise.

Namenode stores all the metadata in its memory, if the replication factor is more, there are more locations for a block that the namenode needs to store, but they are just references to the Datanodes which are already stored in the Namenode.
The Block will be having just references to those Datanodes, so it is negligible as compared to the Block metadata
